# TFLite gives Blob is not defined error when it is required in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, tensorflow-lite, tensorflow.js

TFLite node module gives error when it is required in Node.js, it gives "Blob is not defined" error.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tensorflow/tfjs-tflite

index.js file

```js
require("@tensorflow/tfjs-tflite");
```

package.json file

```js
{
    "name": "tfjs tflite test",
    "version": "1",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
    },
    "license": "UNLICENSED",
    "dependencies": {
        "@tensorflow/tfjs-tflite": "0.0.1-alpha.4",
    }
}
```

You can see the error log here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PInqK.png

Comment: You need to include the code

Comment: Add more details and your question can be reopened afterwards.

Comment: Please be specific @vitaliis otherwise it's not helpful. What are you missing here? Apparently, the OP is trying to use a particular package inside a mocha test which is not starting & running in a browser, therefore it runs on Node, where it fails since it is not built for Node. All this can be easily found and/or deduced from the question.

Comment: Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TFLite is meant for the web - from [tflite's documentation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/tree/master/tfjs-tflite): "*This package enables users to run arbitary TFLite models on the web*". But apparently, you are running it outside of a web environment - in Node.

TFLite contains a statement which resolves stringified JS by using `Blob`, as you can see in `tf-tflite.node.js:1261`. `Blob` is not known to Node, and that's why you get the `ReferenceError` once the module resolution kicks in.

You have several options to get around it in your tests:

1. If you really want to use TF primarily in Node, you are using the wrong package. TF's [documentation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs#about-this-repo) suggests [tfjs-node](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/tree/master/tfjs-node) instead.
2. If you want to run TF primarily in browsers (web) make sure that you [run your Mocha tests in a browser](https://mochajs.org/#running-mocha-in-the-browser)
3. or include a Blob polyfill for Node in your test suite
4. or since you are using CommonJS module resolution, you could avoid TFLite from being run by using spies/mocks and replace the dependency by using [rewire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rewire)